# Angular2 - Init all components in a Tab

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a view which contains Tabbed structure. The Tab has a router link which navigates using routerLink. However, if i navigate to to one of the tabs, only the particular  component is initialized. How do I have all components in the tab have its constructor called.

Parent Template:

```
    <nav>
        <a *ngFor="let tab of tabs" routerLink="{{tab.routerLink}}" routerLinkActive="{{tab.routerLinkActive}}">{{tab.displayText}}</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Parent Component:

```
    loadTabs() {
        this.tabs = [
          {
            routerLink: "/sample/summary/",
            routerLinkActive: "active",
            class: "active",
            displayText: "Summary"
          },
          {
            routerLink: "/sample/details/",
            routerLinkActive: "active",
            class: "active",
            displayText: "Details"
          }
        ]
      }
```

app.routing.ts

```
    export const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'sample',
            component: SampleComponent,
            children: [
              { path: '', redirectTo: 'summary', pathMatch: 'full' },
              { path: 'summary', component: SummaryComponent },
              { path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent }
              ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

When I navigate to `\sample\summary`, `SampleComponent` and `SummaryComponent`  are initiliased but `DetailsComponent` is not. Is there a way to initiliase `DetailsComponent` when `\sample\summary` is navigated with my current setup?